# C++ Vector By Reference

Tags: c++, vector, pass-by-reference, declaration

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <string>

struct LR0Item{
    string lhs;
    vector<string> rhs;
    int dpos;
};
map<string,vector<string> > NTmap;

for(map<string,vector<string> >::iterator it=NTmap.begin(); it!=NTmap.end();++it){
    string lhs = it->first;
    vector<vector<string> > &L = it->second;         //?????
    for(unsigned i=0;i<L.size();i++){       //?????
        vector<string> &rhs = L[i];         //?????
```

I posted my code above, the full program is too lengthy to include.
My question has to do with mainly the first and third 'comments'.

```
vector<vector<string> > &L = it->second;
```

I am not sure what this is saying, is it saying copy the vector stored at it->second into a vector named L?  I am also unsure what '&L' is saying.

```
vector<string> &rhs = L[i];
```

This is the same situation, is this copying vector from L[i] into rhs?

Are these creating the vector rhs and vector L   or are they assuming they vectors are already created.  What is the point in creating a vector every time I loop, simply for the purpose of being able to loop through the inner workings of the map?

My second comment:

```
for(unsigned i=0;i<L.size();i++){
```

I am wondering what this loop is actually looping through, if I have a vector from it->second, being store into its own vector L, is this loop looping through each string in the inner vector?

P.s. this was pseudo code givin' by an instructor, I am trying to understand it.

Comment: Neither of those references and their initializations are valid. The map iterator has type `std::vector<std::string>` of the `second` member, thus making the initialization to a reference of type `std::vector<std::vector<std::string>>` invalid. the subsequent reference for `rhs` is equally invalid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`L` and `rhs` are not vectors, they are *references* to vectors. That's what the `&` means. So

```
vector<vector<string> > &L = it->second;
```

makes `L` a reference to the vector stored at `it->second`. So later when writing `L.size()` it has the same effect as if `it->second.size()` has been written.

The main difference from what you said is that nothing is copied and nothing is created when you make a reference. You are just refering to existing objects.

Comment: My question would then be, why is a vector<vector<string> > being made to reference a single vector<string> ?  Does this even work and what does it mean if it does?

Comment: @user244014 I hadn't noticed that, it's not correct, presumably it's just a mistake.